# Debugging Azure IoT Module with iotedgehubdev throws an error

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I'm running:

- Windows 10 Home version 1909.
- Visual Studio 2019 Pro 16.5.0. Azure
- IoT Edge Tools 1.7.0. azure-iot-sdk-c package.
- Latest version of Docker Toolbox - (it runs hello-world with no errors).
- Python, pip. iotedgehubdev 0.13.0

Did the following steps:

1. Registered account on Azure
2. Created free IoT hub
3. Registered Edge Device
4. (Not sure if it was needed) Created VM, installed Azure Runtime, registered it in IoT Hub as device from step 3.
5. (Not sure if it was needed) Started registry in docker with command `docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`
6. Created Win 64 Azure Module project in Visual Studio with default settings including the repository URL (localhost:5000/moduleName)
7. Set up iotedgehubdev with device connection string taken from device from step 3.
8. Set the module's project as startup project
9. Trying to start debug

Module is built, but debugging does not start.

Output of IoT Hub in Visual Studio:

```
IoT Hub edge module IotEdgeModule1 is using \"input1\" as inputs
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\iotedgehubdev\v0.13.0\iotedgehubdev modulecred -l -m "target"
EdgeHubConnectionString=HostName=MyTestHub.azure-devices.net;GatewayHostName=localhost;DeviceId=myEdgeDevice;ModuleId=target;SharedAccessKey=heres_the_key
EdgeModuleCACertificateFile=C:\ProgramData\iotedgehubdev\data\certs\edge-device-ca\cert\edge-device-ca.cert.pem
DOCKER_HOST: 
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 
DOCKER_CERT_PATH: 
Additional Env Variables: 
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\iotedgehubdev\v0.13.0\iotedgehubdev start -i "input1"
IoT Edge Simulator has been started in single module mode.
Please run `iotedgehubdev modulecred` to get credential to connect your module.
And send message through:
        curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"inputName": "input1","data":"hello world"}' http://localhost:53000/api/v1/messages
Please refer to https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-testing-utility/blob/master/swagger.json for detail schema
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
Starting to check connectivity for local port 8883...
[ERROR]: Failed to connect to local port 8883 in specified time, please try again later.
[ERROR]: Failed to start CLI in specified time.
C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\iotedgehubdev\v0.13.0\iotedgehubdev stop
IoT Edge Simulator has been stopped successfully.
```

I tried disabling Windows Defender, restarting - no luck. Visual Studio is started with admin permisions. Is there any other component needed? I have fully followed the [guide on azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-visual-studio-develop-module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled Windows to 10 Pro instead of Home which allowed me to use Docker Desktop instead of legacy Docker Toolbox solution. The issue is now fixed.